# html and css button wont align with a preexisting form

Tags: html, css

The below code is setup as a form login button and text input, I have added a (now functioning) button inline with the other form pieces, live preview and live view in Dreamweaver both show everything working and aligning great. Upon uploading to the live site the new button shoots up to the top and "fuses" with the header menu. Any advice on how I can get it to stay where it is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Random Login Form</title>
            <style>
            /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree
             * needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if
             * they are on local disk! */

                /* Change the white to any color ;) */
            input: -webkit-autofill {-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;}

            body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .body{
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                z-index: 0
            }

            .header{
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                right: 192px;
                z-index: 2;
            }

            .header div{
                float: left;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family: 'Avant Garde', 'Avantgarde', 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 200;
                width: 700px;
                height: 26px;
                background: rgba(26,26,26,.3);
                border: 0px solid #660033;
                border-radius: 0px;
                padding-left: 6px; 
                padding-top: 5px;
            }

            .header div span{
                color: #5379fa !important;
            }

            .login{
                position: absolute;
                right: 20px;
                width: 640px;
                z-index: 2;
            }

            .login input[type=text]{
                width: 200px;
                height: 20px;
                background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
                border: 0px solid #660033;
                border-radius: 0px;
                color: #660033;
                font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .login input[type=password]{
                width: 200px;
                height: 20px;
                background: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
                border: 6px solid rgba(169,0,86,0.8);
                border-radius: 2px;
                color: #660033;
                font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding: 0px;
                margin-top: 10px;           
            }

            .login input[type=submit]{
                width: 100px;
                height: 25px;
                background: #660033;
                border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 0px;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding: 2px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }

            .login input[type=submit]:hover{
                background: #510028;
            }

            .login input[type=button]:active{
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

            .login input[type=text]:focus{
                outline: none;
                border: 1px solid #660033;
            }

            .login input[type=password]:focus{
                outline: none;
                border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
            }

            .login input[type=button]:focus{
                outline: none;
            }

            ::-webkit-input-placeholder{
                color: #660033;
            }

            ::-moz-input-placeholder{
                color: #660033;
            }

            .enroll-btn {
                position: absolute;
                right: 195px;
                width: 150px;
                z-index: 2;
                height: 15px;
                background: #660033;
                border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding:4px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .enroll-btn:hover {
                background-color: #510028;
            }

            </style>
            <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <body>          
        <script src="https://tether.netteller.com/citizensebank/login.js"></script> 
        <a href="https://www.netteller.com/login2008/Authentication/Views/OnlineEnrollmentAgreement.aspx" class="enroll-btn">Consumer Enroll Now</a>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it might be because of position:absolute to .enroll-btn remove position absolute and check.

Comment: What is the live site URL?